# ASP.Net Looping Through Gridview After adding Group Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In a GridView I am adding Grouping rows to the underlying table in the RowDataBound, but when I ApplyChanges and loop through each GridViewRow not all rows can be tested for TextBox value etc, the number of rows is reduced by the number of grouping rows inserted. Although it does loop through the grouping rows which I ignore, and misses the last n rows.

```
Private tmpSiteName As String = ""

Private Sub gvVehicles_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvVehicles.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        If tmpSiteName <> drv("lcname").ToString() Then
            tmpSiteName = drv("lcname").ToString()

            Dim tbl As Table = TryCast(e.Row.Parent, Table)
            If tbl IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim row As New GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
                Dim cell As New TableCell()

                ' Span the row across all of the columns in the Gridview
                cell.ColumnSpan = Me.gvVehicles.Columns.Count

                cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
                'cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold")
                cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#f5f5f5")
                cell.Style.Add("color", "#000000")

                Dim span As New HtmlGenericControl("span")
                span.InnerHtml = tmpSiteName

                cell.Controls.Add(span)
                row.Cells.Add(cell)

                tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyChanges()
    Dim AuctionDB As fleet.AuctionDB = New fleet.AuctionDB
    Dim OldFleetNo As String = ""
    Dim NewFleetNo As String = ""
    Dim OldReserve As Integer = 0
    Dim NewReserve As Integer = 0
    Dim MTA As Long = 0
    Dim Sitekey As String = ""
    Dim vcaudit As Long = 0

    Dim i As Integer = gvVehicles.Rows.Count

    Try
        For Each DRow As GridViewRow In gvVehicles.Rows

            Sitekey = TryCast(DRow.FindControl("hiddenSitekey"), HiddenField).Value
            MTA = Val(TryCast(DRow.FindControl("hiddenMTA"), HiddenField).Value)

            strChange = ""

            ' The Grouping rows throw up funny results, but we can catch MTA = 0
            If MTA > 0 Then
                OldFleetNo = TryCast(DRow.FindControl("hiddenFleetNo"), HiddenField).Value
                NewFleetNo = TryCast(DRow.FindControl("txtFleetNo"), TextBox).Text
                If NewFleetNo <> OldFleetNo Then
                    vcaudit = AuctionDB.FleetUpdates(Sitekey, MTA, "FLEET NO", OldReserve, NewFleetNo, Session("user_name"))
                    updateCount += 1
                    strChange = "Fleet No. changed from " & OldFleetNo & " to " & NewFleetNo & "<br /><br />"
                End If
            End If
        Next DRow

    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowMessage("Error: " & ex.Message, "alert-danger")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You posted a lot of code. please make a minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have paired back the code

Comment: So no takers, my first stackoverflow question and tumbleweeds :)